# I tried to change my URL and ended up losing access to my site? I went into general settings and changed both WordPress URL and Site URL

Tags: customization

******i got this error message, [this site can't be reached after trying to change my site URL to https://customize-WordPress-sample.local/] after trying to customize my site in general setting*** my site domain name is www.emeylizzy.com.ng*** please  need your help because am new in wordpress org

Comment: So your website was live on www.emeylizzy.com.ng and on the live website you changed the URL? Why did you do that? Do you want a local backup?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the URL back to the old situation, so that it works again, do this:

1. Go to your hosting providers dashboard and look for sth called 'PHP My Admin'. That is the 'back-end' of the Wordpress database. If you can't find it, please contact your hosting provider to ask where it is (and what the login information is).
2. Login to PHP My Admin and select the database that your Wordpress site is linked to.
3. Go to wp_options (if you have changed the prefix during the installation, it will be called prefix_options) and look for the **siteurl** field and the **home** field. Then change the URL back to www.emeylizzy.com.ng.

This should fix the problem.

If you want to move or copy the website to a new domain (or local development), do this:

1. Keep your current website as it is! Don't change URLs or things like that.
2. Install a fresh Wordpress installation on the domain or local domain where you want to move the Wordpress site. Create and link a **new** database.
3. Copy the website with the Duplicator plugin. It is very extensively explained, including a video, on [WP Shout](https://wpshout.com/quick-guides/move-a-wordpress-site-with-the-duplicator-plugin/).
4. Note that the website www.emeylizzy.com.ng will still work, you are only making a copy. If you create a copy of your current website for development purposes, you can follow the exact same procedure with the Duplicator plugin, only then are you cloning (copying) the development website and importing it on www.emeylizzy.com.ng.